# costmap_plugins.xml misbehaving

Tags: ros, navigation, compile, costmap, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created a new layer (the `overwrite_layer`) and declared it in the `costmap_plugins.xml`. The code compiles without errors but when I run it, I get the following error message:

```
[ INFO] [1401350861.147988001, 1397467592.599155280]: Using plugin "overwrite_layer"
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pluginlib::LibraryLoadException'
  what():  According to the loaded plugin descriptions the class scitos_2d_navigation::OverwriteLayer with base class type costmap_2d::Layer does not exist. Declared types are blablabla ...
```

The puzzeling part to me is, that the plugin loader still looks for a `costmap_2d::Layer` object even though it is clearly defined as a `costmap_2d::CostmapLayer` (see `costmap_plugins.xml`-file below). Acutally I had it first as a `costmap_2d::Layer`, compiled it, then changed it to `costmap_2d::CostmapLayer` and then compiled it again. Can I maybe force the compiler somehow to reread the `costmap_plugins.xml`? Or am I overlooking something obvious? Thanks!

```
<class_libraries>
    <library path="lib/libdynamic_layer">
        <class type="scitos_2d_navigation::DynamicLayer" base_class_type="costmap_2d::Layer">
            <description>Publishing a static_map and a dynamic_map based on old and current measurments</description>
        </class>
    </library>
    <library path="lib/liboverwrite_layer">
        <class type="scitos_2d_navigation::OverwriteLayer" base_class_type="costmap_2d::CostmapLayer">
            <description>Overwriting the layered costmap with a user defined map.</description>
        </class>
    </library>
</class_libraries>
```

I'm on Hydro, Ubuntu 12.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/171396/costmap_plugins.xml-misbehaving/) by [Luke_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/15276/luke_ros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 116 on 2014-05-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The base class HAS to be costmap_2d::Layer -- the plugin loader is templated on that base class and can only find/load such a class. Even if your class derives from costmap_2d::CostmapLayer, that class derives from costmap_2d::Layer and so your class eventually has a base class of costmap_2d::Layer, and that is what has to be in the plugins.xml file in order for pluginlib to find the class.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-05-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Luke_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/15276/luke_ros/) on 2014-05-30**:
Thanks. That helps a lot. For the ultimate learning experience: Where can I look that up?

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2014-05-30**:
The docs you want to look at are those for pluginlib: http://wiki.ros.org/pluginlib which is used throughout ROS.